# Convert the following expression to use only NAND gates

Tags: math, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have the following expression ( `'`denotes `NOT`)...

```
e'(a+b)
```

First I expand...

```
e'a + e'b
```

DeMorgan's Law...

```
(e'a +e'b)'
((e'a)'(e'b)')'
```

Now I am stuck. Each `NAND` gate that I use can only accept a maximum of 2 inputs. I can use as many `NAND` gates as I want, but I should try to come up with an expression that uses the least amount of gates.

Am I on the right track? How do I continue further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest taking this:

```
e'(a+b)
```

And writing it using a more verbose notation to make the transformations easier to recognize as having been done correctly:

```
(not e) and (a or b)
```

As Rory Daulton suggested, a good first step is to know how to render the basic logical operations using nand.

1. not e can be shown to be equivalent to e nand e, as Rory pointed out.
2. you can show that a and b is equivalent to not (a nand b) by the definition of nand. Using the above result, we recover the equivalent expression (a nand b) nand (a nand b) using only nand gates.
3. you can show that a or b is equivalent to not((not a) and (not b)) by De Morgan, hence (not a) nand (not b) by the definition of nand. We can use the above results to derive the equivalent expression (a nand a) nand (b nand b) using only nand gates.

Returning to our expression:

```
(not e) and (a or b)
```

I sort of like working outside-in, so we start with the outermost operation, and, and use the rule from 2 above to get:

```
(not e) and (a or b)
2=> ((not e) nand (a or b)) nand ((not e) nand (a or b))
```

Now that we have four subexpressions at the same level, we can start from the left and work our way right:

```
(not e) and (a or b)
2=> ((not e) nand (a or b)) nand ((not e) nand (a or b))
1=> ((e nand e) nand (a or b)) nand ((not e) nand (a or b))
3=> ((e nand e) nand ((a nand a) nand (b nand b))) nand ((not e) nand (a or b))
1=> ((e nand e) nand ((a nand a) nand (b nand b))) nand ((e nand e) nand (a or b))
3=> ((e nand e) nand ((a nand a) nand (b nand b))) nand ((e nand e) nand ((a nand a) nand (b nand b)))
```

A circuit for this might look like:

```
e--+---|\   e'
   |   > >o----------------------|\  (e'(a+b))'
   +---|/                        > >o--------+---|\
                             +---|/          |   > >o--e'(a+b)
a--+---|\   a'               |               +---|/
   |   > >o--------|\        |
   +---|/          > >o------+
               +---|/   a+b
b--+---|\      |
   |   > >o----+
   +---|/   b'
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not look like the right track.

Your original expression has only three operations: NOT (`e'`), OR (`a+b`), and AND (between the last two expressions I gave). You should figure out how to do each of those three operations, then combine them into one overall structure. Knowing how to do each of these is critical in this kind of problem.

Here is how to do the first: `NOT x` is equivalent to `x NAND x`, therefore `e'` is equivalent to `e NAND e`. Continue from here.

Comment: OK I understand. I came up with `(((ee)'a)'((ee)'b)')'`. How does this answer look to you. By the looks of it, I think I can create this using only `NAND` gates.